# Mongodb iso datetime

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, datetime

I need to recover date from mongodb iso date formate by angular js. How can I recover this? please help me.

Mongodb iso date: 2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z

My convert type: 28-12-2013  8:30:17

Comment: What do you mean by *recover*? Are you getting ISO 8601 timestamps in your client-side code and you want to display them in a different format?

Comment: I want to show only date from mongodb iso datetime

Comment: Yes I want to show ISO time stamps in organized way.

Comment: You will need to cast the timestamps to a JS date object, e.g., `var foo = new Date('2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z')` will give you a proper `Date` object.

Comment: Yes got it. In my code i have used in my js code : var foo = new Date(time); $scope.newtime=foo;  To show newtime I have written: {{newtime| date:date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}. And it shows actual organized output. But can you ensure me that, in here (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z)  & this Z will changed with country ? I need to ensure this, if you know please inform me. I need to change Z with country.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
var date = new Date("2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z");
$scope.displayDate = date.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I really recommend http://momentjs.com/. they have a good format function.

Ex.

```
moment('2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

Will give the answer

```
28-12-2013 08:30:17
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to get the time as per mongo,

1. get the value in your controller from the mongoDB.
2. Use that value to store in the variable.
3. Convert it to the ISO format easily using .toISOString() method and its done.
   Here is sample..

   ```
    getdate.controller(..){
    $scope.fromdate=date.toISOString();
    console.log($scope.fromdate);
    }
   ```

   Now you can get in the MongoDB format..